# Copy activity fails while adding additional columns in parquet file

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have been trying to add additional column in parquet file through copy activity pipeline to copy from csv file to parquet
but it is giving me error the column name is invalid. Column name cannot contain these character:[,;{}()\n\t=]

I am adding only filename as column name in additional column at source and taking $$filepath as value.

Comment: Does the filename have any character ."[,;{}()\n\t=]" ?

Comment: No it doesn't have

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced the above and got the same error.

[image]

The above error occurs when we give special characters (`,;{}()\n\t=`) in the column name of the additional column. For Parquet file special characters not allowed for columns names.

[image]

When we avoid the above special characters in the column name, we can get desired result.

[image]

**Parquet file:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your inputs 
however, I am using same filename only as column name